# Write in MySQL table, if same does not exist

Tags: php, mysql

I try to write in DB table, but before I need check that the same var doesn't exist in column. But my code doesn't workd correctly for empty table. How to fix it to it start to work for empty table and later?

```
    try
    {
        //$sql = "SELECT id FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$col." = :value";
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM column WHERE name = :value";
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':value', $value);
        $relut = $s->execute();
        verifyVarDump($relut, '$relut: ');
        verifyVarDump($s, '$s: ');

        foreach($s as $row)
        {
            echo ' :OK: ';
            if(is_int($row['id']))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                $valuesUnique[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Не удалось читать БД';
        exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to consider putting a unique constraint on that column.  Then, the database would largely handle the problem of a potentially duplicate insert.

Comment: I think what you really need to do is [check the PHP Manual for PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) It is written in many languages. There are many misunderstandings in this code

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , thanks.
RiggsFolly, I know it's bad code, will correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim's comment is what you need, but as you probably don't know what a "constraint" is, here are the steps (it's actually much simpler that what you are doing)

1) In your table definition: add either a primary key index, or a unique index. A little bit of light reading (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html).

What this means is, if you try to add another entry with the same value, it will fail and throw and error. And you use this to your advantage.

2) You then add in the new row with "INSERT INTO" , and it'll fail if it the value exists in your "unique" column, or work if it doesn't. Simple. One query does it all :)

There are two other tricks you can do:

a) You can do a "REPLACE INTO" and that says "If the unique key does not exists, add in the new row; if it does exists then delete the row first and then add in my new one"

b) You can do a "INSERT INTO ..... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" and that says "If the unique key does not exists, add in the new row; if it does exists then modify the existing row with the UPDATES in the second half.

Two more single line queries that do all you need!

Good luck.